# How do we plot \$u(t−τ)\$

Tags: signal

When analyzing simple circuits to understand the theory of their operation, we often make use of the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), \$u(t)\$.

When we calculate a convolution integral, we must understand the time-reversed and delayed function \$u(t-\tau)\$.

How do we plot \$u(t−τ) \$ ?

What is the range of \$\tau\$ for which the value of \$u(t−τ)\$ is 1.

\$u(t−τ)\$=\$u(−(τ-t))\$.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as "off topic". It is directly related to "the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces" which is on-topic per the FAQ.

Comment: @ThePhoton I flagged this as off topic since the first revision looked like math to me and I didn't see it actually was the Heaviside step function. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 4):

The step function is one when it's argument is greater than or equal to zero, as the wiki page you linked to says.

Therefore, to determine when the function outputs a 1, you need to determine when it's argument meets the above definition. So you have the equation

$$t-\tau \ge 0$$

When is this true? When

$$t \ge \tau$$

So really \$u(t-r)\$ is just a delay with respect to the variable t. There are some very good interactive tools for understanding this kind of stuff [here](http://www.jhu.edu/signals/index.html). As you can see in the "Joy of Convolution" applet on the linked page, the step function is frequently used with respect to tau, in which case it is time-reversed as you mentioned.

Comment: One thing I'd maybe reword, though. You say "`u(t-r)` is just a shift". But usually when we use this we're actually integrating with respect to `r`. And if you look at this as a function of `r`, with `t` as a parameter, then it's both time-reversed and shifted.

Answer (score 1):

> How do we plot \$u(t-\tau)\$ ?

Like Nick points out, it's a very simple function. Whenever \$t-\tau\$ is greater than zero, the value is 1, otherwise it's 0.

One more thing to point out though, is that when we use this function, we're usually calculating a convolution integral like

\$\int_a^bh(\tau)u(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\$

To visualize what's going on in this integral we really want to plot \$u(t-\tau)\$ as a function of \$\tau\$, not *t*. That means you want to think of the result as being 1 when \$\tau < t\$ and 0 when \$\tau \ge t\$, instead of the other way around.

[image]